# Dynamic Memory Deletion in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

[image]I am using _aligned_malloc in my code. But it is throwing error error as shown in image.

```
CString sBuffer = _T("Hello");
TCHAR*   pBuffer; 

pBuffer = (TCHAR *)_aligned_malloc(1024, 16);

if (pBuffer == NULL) {
    ...............Error .. msg 
}

pBuffer =  sBuffer.GetBuffer(sBuffer.GetLength());

..................................................
.........................................................

sBuffer.ReleaseBuffer(sBuffer.GetLength());

if (pBuffer != NULL) {
    _aligned_free(pBuffer);
}
```

Comment: `pBuffer =  sBuffer.GetBuffer(...)` After this, `pBuffer` no longer points to the block of memory allocated with `_aligned_malloc` (that block of memory is leaked) - it points to a block of memory allocated by `sBuffer.GetBuffer()`. Further, after subsequent `sBuffer.ReleaseBuffer()` call, `pBuffer` is a dangling pointer, and should not be used for anything - least of all for attempting to free memory it no longer points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CString` class implements `(LPCTSTR)` cast operator that you can use to get `const TCHAR*`. 
Please note that `TCHAR` is defined as `char` in **MBCS** mode, and as `wchar` in **UNICODE** mode. For more details please refer to *tchar.h* where its defined.

If you'd like to modify the content of the buffer you'll need to use `GetBuffer()` method. Don't forget to call `ReleaseBuffer()` when you done. So, there is no need to allocate memory manually.

You can also easily construct `CString` from `TCHAR*`. There is a constructor to do that.